# Selecting a file from a directory

Tags: java, android, file

I have a directory that is displayed in a `ListView`. Inside each folder there is a `.txt` file called **Sales ...(Sales112855,Sales122921,Sales122941, ..., )**.
There is a cat for sorting through files. That is, by clicking on an item from the list, it goes inside the folder and goes through the files there.

The code:

```
File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();
        for (File f : listFile) {
            if (f.isDirectory() && (!f.getAbsolutePath().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(dir)))) {
                File[] listFile2 = f.listFiles();
                for (File f2 : listFile2) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "f2 " + f2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "f " + f, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Problems like this. I do not know how to make it stop at the file I need. tricks for JDK 8+ I will not be able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `break`, once you found your file

```
                for (File f2 : listFile2) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "f2 " + f2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 if (f2.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                   // found file
                     break;
                  }
                }
```

Comment: as you are iterating files, check if current file property matches expected one in if condition

Comment: then this code needs to return the file found

Comment: `to make it stop at the file I need`- You need to decide what conditions file has to meet, so that it is the file you are looking for

Comment: i have updated if condition to check if filename ends with `.txt`, check updated answer

Comment: if you want to get all files with `.txt` extention then in if condition don't break out,  just collect all `.txt` into list of files